# Django: Making a Notification Engine

Tags: python, django, notifications, functional-programming, django-rest-framework

I've been building a email/sms notification engine. A person or group can be subscribed to an object and if the object gets updated, the people/groups will be notified of the change by email/sms.

Currently, I've implemented it as below:

## models.py

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    # subscribers
    people  = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
    groups  = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

    # mandatory fields for generic relation
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

## mixins.py

```
class NotificationMixin(object):

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        model_name = str.lower(serializer.Meta.model)
        old_obj = model.objects.get(id=serializer.data['id'])
        obj = serializer.save()
        self.notify(model_name, old_obj, obj)

    def notify(self, model_name, old_obj, obj):
        # All models have a GenericRelation field for reverse searching
        subscriptions = Subscription.objects.filter(**{ model_name: obj })

        // *rest of logic to iterate over subscriptions and email people/groups
```

Using django's ContentType generic relations, I can subscribe a person/group to any object.

I want to add the capability to create global subscriptions using the same Subscription model so that they are all stored in the same table. A global subscription will not have an object that it is tracking, but when any object of a specific model is triggered, emails will be sent.

I'm having trouble generalizing my subscription model to be able to accept a model instance or the model for triggering a response.

The functionality I want:

1. Global Subscriptions

   - People/Groups updated by if any object of the model X is changed
2. Object Level Subscriptions

   - People/Groups updated if specific object is updated

Is the current model/architecture that I have a good way to go about this problem, or should I approach this differently?

**Note** The frontend is in AngularJs, so this is exclusively interacting with our django api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody who may want to find a solution to this, I ended up doing:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    """
    Model for subscribing to object changes.

    Can be subscribed to any object or any model type.
    Subcriptions:
    model - if any object changes of this type that belongs to the company, update
    object - if that specific object changes, update

    To create:
    Either give a content_object or a content_type. Content object is a model instance. Content type is a ContentType (i.e. Study, Product, etc.)

    If it is created wrong, will just be lost in database forever (unless you know it's there, then delete it.)
    """
    people = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
    trigger = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    APP_LABELS = [apps to limit the available choices]

    # for object subscription
    # mandatory fields for generic relation
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
        Save logic to validate the Subscription model. This is run after the native create() method.
        '''
        # check if no content_object, then content_type must be defined by user
        # probably not necessary since it will fail at creation if content_type isn't an instance of a ContentType, but good to double check
        if not self.content_object:
            if self.content_type.__class__ != ContentType:
                if type(self.content_type) == str:
                    # if content_type is a string designating a model
                    self.content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=self.content_type)
                else:
                    # if content_type is a model class
                    self.content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Study)

        apps = ', '.join(map(str, self.APP_LABELS))

        # check if content_type in our defined apps
        if self.content_type.app_label not in apps:
            raise ValidationError('Please select a content_object or content_type in apps: {0}'.format(apps))

        super(Subscription, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: How did you use the `trigger` field?

Comment: hi @schlumpfpirat, unfortunately I don't remember exactly how I triggered this. It's been a few years since I've coded in Django, I'm sorry!

I'm guessing it was triggered via cronjob or a subscription event that the system was listening for.